# How to insert particular columns of an XLS into MS SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, import-from-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet of about 1000 rows and about 15 columns. What I would like to do is to import this data into a table, but selectively. I want data from Row 5(say) onwards till about 5 rows from the end of the sheet. This is because the number of rows may vary, but I am sure that I will not need the last 4-5 rows irrespective of the number of rows in the spreadsheet. Additionally, I would like to insert only a few columns, as, Col1-Col5, Col7-Col9, and Col12-Col15. Is there one command/sequence of commands that I can use to achieve this? Please let me know ASAP. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code down there creates a file with SQL instructions based on what's in your xls. You just have to add a Macro, paste it, and change a few things (add a while to fill the ColFields Collection with the title line where the column names must match the table field names, declare what's not, give a value to fileName...). 
Then execute the Macro and you'll have a file with all the insert you want, then you'll just have to execute this file on your base.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim NbOfLines = Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row - 5 'Not the 5 last lines
    Dim ColFields As New Collection 'Do a while on the title line to fill the collection with wanted columns titles (do not add ignored columns)

    Dim StartSql As String
        StartSql = "INSERT INTO " + TableName + "("
        For Each loopField In ColFields
            StartSql = StartSql + loopField + ","
        Next
        StartSql = Left(StartSql, Len(StartSql) - 1)
        StartSql = StartSql + ") SELECT "


    Dim Value As String
    For i = 1 To NbOfLines
    Sql = ""
        j = 1
        For Each loopField In ColFields
            Value = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(i, j).Value
            Sql = Sql + IIf(Value = "", "NULL", "'" + Replace(Value, "'", "''") + "'") + ","
            j = j + 1
        Next
        Sql = Left(Sql, Len(Sql) - 1)
        Sql = StartSql + Sql + vbCrLf
        Call WriteLine(Sql, FileName)
    Next


    End Sub


    Public Sub WriteLine(Ligne As String, FileName As String)

    Open FileName For Append As #1
        Print #1, Ligne
    Close
    End Sub
```

edit : I know it's not the best method (nor the most beautiful one), I gave it to you cos' I used it a few weeks ago to import data from a DB to another (but I needed to do it only once, not everyday).
I also know there is a way to do it with an OpenRowSet you're right about it, but I just don't know how (I'll go often on this page wishing someone'll teach me).
Finally, I encourage you to read this page : [A Blog Page With A Solution](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/)
(You'll find the great procedure 'uftReadfileAsTable' here : [The Procedure Code](http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/uftReadFileAsTable.txt))
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) Is there no easier way than this? Is there a way to do the same thing using an openrowset? And, if I am to use this file, where do I put it? Also, the file name will be different each day. How to account for its "dynamic" nature? Additionally, looking at this code, am I correct in assuming that the column name in the table and the ones in the file are to be the same, ie, because of the while loop that I'll be running? Please let me know as and when you can.

Comment: I guess what I really want to know is if there is an SQL command to do this. To make it simple. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Will look into the links. Thanks!